# Archive option is not active in android project

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, archive

[I cannot Archive my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyrSq.png)

[image]

Archive option is not active in android project
or in build menu is not active

Answer (score 1):

Check the following:

- You are in Release config
- The project is not running

Answer (score 0):

Check if Android SDK manager is enabled. tools->Anrdoid

Comment: it is not  enabled how can I make it enable

Comment: please, refer to this link https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/85853/archive-option-is-disabled-in-visual-studio-2015. If your folder is empty as well, you can download SDK here - https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/manual_installation/

Comment: can't see a message, try commenting again

Answer (score 0):

It seems VS installer deleted the "tools" folder under Android SDK folder. 
To check that go to Tools > Android and check if options here is available. If all options are gray go to Tools > Options > Xamarin > Open location from "Android SDK Location" input. From there go to tools folder. If there is nothing here you need to download it from https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-windows.zip, and then copy the "tools" folder back to previously copied path tools folder. Now, all options are available again.